# Создание матрицы и ее вывод

Tags: python

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(matrix[i][j], end=' ')
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Код

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        matrix.append(int(input()))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
       print(matrix[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```

Как вывести  `matrix` содержащую в себе `int`?

Comment: matrix у тебя одномерный список, а ты обращаешься к нему как к двумерному

Comment: А как тоогда к нему правильно обратиться?

Comment: Одномерный - один уровень индекса. Вот и используй один, а не два.

Answer (score 2):

```
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = list()
for i in range(n):
    temp = []
    for j in range(m):
        temp.append(int(input()))
    matrix.append(temp)


for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(matrix[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: ну во, совсем другое дело!